# How to let player know they've won hangman?

Tags: python

I'm working on a mystery word game (hangman) problem in python. For the most part everything works other than telling the player that they've actually won the game.

I've taken a variety of approaches to trying to solve this problem.

Unfortunately, I've done so far has allowed me to tell the user that they've correctly guessed the word aka they've won. If someone could provide me with a solution or guide me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
def guess_taker():
    import random
    f = open("words.txt")
    all_words = (f.read()).upper()


    split_all_words = all_words.split()

    easy_words = []
    normal_words = []
    hard_words = []
    for word in split_all_words:
        if len(word) >= 8:
            hard_words.append(word)
        elif len(word) >= 6 and len(word) <= 8:
            normal_words.append(word)
        elif len(word) <= 6 and len(word) >= 4:
            easy_words.append(word)


    difficulty_selector = input("Welcome to the Mystery Word Game!\n\nPlease enter your difficulty level:\n\nEASY\nNORMAL\nHARD\n")
    upper_case_difficulty = difficulty_selector.upper()

    while upper_case_difficulty not in ["EASY", "NORMAL", "HARD"]:
        print("INVALID ENTRY: Please try again!")
        difficulty_selector = input("Welcome to the Mystery Word Game!\n\nPlease enter your difficulty level: \n\nEASY\nNORMAL\nHARD\n")
        upper_case_difficulty = difficulty_selector.upper()


    if upper_case_difficulty == "EASY":
        word = random.choice(easy_words)
    elif upper_case_difficulty == "NORMAL":
        word = random.choice(normal_words)
    elif upper_case_difficulty == "HARD":
        word = random.choice(hard_words)

    word_match = word.replace("", " ")
    word_match = word_match.strip()

    print("This word is",len(word),"characters long")
    current_guesses= []

    def display_letter(letter, guesses):
        """
        Conditionally display a letter. If the letter is already in
        the list `guesses`, then return it. Otherwise, return "_".
        """
        if letter in guesses:
            return letter
        else:
            return "_"

    def print_word(word, guesses):
        output_letters = []
        for letter in word:
            output_letters.append(display_letter(letter, guesses))
        print("".join(output_letters))

    guess_counter = 8
    print(word_match)
    print("Lives remaining: ", guess_counter)
    guess = input("Please input your letter guess: ").upper()


    wordGuessed = False

    while guess_counter > 0 and wordGuessed is False:
        if word == print_word(word, current_guesses):
            wordGuessed is True
            print("You won")
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print("ERROR! Please enter one letter.")       
        if guess in word and len(guess) == 1 and guess not in current_guesses:
            print("Correct!", guess, "is in the word!")
        if guess not in word and guess not in current_guesses:
            print("Sorry,", guess, "is not in the word.")
            guess_counter -= 1
        if guess in current_guesses:
            print("INVALID ENTRY! Already been guessed!")
        if guess not in current_guesses and len(guess) == 1:
            current_guesses.append(guess)
        if guess_counter > 0:
            print_word(word, current_guesses)
            print("Current guesses: ", current_guesses)
            print("Lives remaining: ", guess_counter, "\n")
            guess = input("Please input your letter guess:").upper()

    print("GAME OVER! The word was", word.upper())
    end_game = input("Play again? Type Yes or No. ")
    end_game = end_game.lower()

    if end_game == "yes":
        guess_taker()
    else:
        print("Good-bye!")

guess_taker()
```

The program currently requires a text file to import a list of words. I've also altered the program to tell you what the word is so that you can easily "win"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets change print_word to have it return the word to allow for comparison:

```
def print_word(word, guesses):
    output_letters = []
    for letter in word:
        output_letters.append(display_letter(letter, guesses))
    return ("".join(output_letters))
```

And move the conditions including a break for a win:

```
while guess_counter > 0 and wordGuessed is False:
    if len(guess) != 1:
        print("ERROR! Please enter one letter.")
    if guess in word and len(guess) == 1 and guess not in current_guesses:
        print("Correct!", guess, "is in the word!")
        if guess not in current_guesses and len(guess) == 1:
            current_guesses.append(guess)
            if word == print_word(word, current_guesses):
                wordGuessed is True
                print("You won")
                break
    if guess not in word and guess not in current_guesses:
        print("Sorry,", guess, "is not in the word.")
        guess_counter -= 1
    if guess in current_guesses:
        print("INVALID ENTRY! Already been guessed!")
    if guess_counter > 0:
        print(print_word(word, current_guesses))
        print("Current guesses: ", current_guesses)
        print("Lives remaining: ", guess_counter, "\n")
        guess = input("Please input your letter guess:").upper()
```

Comment: This was exactly the piece of the puzzle I was missing! I spent many hours trying to figure out what was wrong. It's very interesting to know it was such a minor thing. Thank you so much!